# How to redirect file.php to file, but make file point to file.php?

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess

I'm trying to clean up my URLs using `mod_rewrite` in my .htaccess files.

Let's say I have the following files on my server:

```
/about.php
/contact.php
```

If a user types `about` or `contact`, I want `about.php` or `contact.php` to be displayed to the user, but ensuring the URL stays the same (i.e. it all happens server-side). Similarly, if the user enters `about.php` or `contact.php`, I want it to 301 redirect to `about` or `contact`, which will then pull the page server-side, whilst keeping a pretty URL.

What I have tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule about about.php
RewriteRule contact contact.php
RewriteRule about.php about [R]
RewriteRule contact.php contact [R]
```

That results in a circular redirect loop.

And the other way round:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule about.php about [R]
RewriteRule contact.php contact [R]
RewriteRule about about.php
RewriteRule contact contact.php
```

This is functional, but the redirect doesn't work (the URL stays the same).

How can I make it so that I don't get a redirect loop but my pages will all point to the version without `.php`?

*Note: I know that `[R]` is 302 not 301 but I'm using 302 for testing.*

Comment: Not really a PHP question - but remember to enter delimiters for your redirect, ie. ^about/$ otherwise everything with 'about' in it will redirect to about.php (eg. about/xyz/ will redirect to about.php). Also find it a bit weird that you want to redirect `/about/` to `about.php` but then you also want to redirect `about.php` to `/about/` - just seem to be going around in circles...

Comment: @MrJ I don't want to redirect `/about` to `/about.php` - I want apache to simply show `about.php` for `about`

Comment: They want it so when you browse to /about/ the script about.php executes without forwarding. As well as not let them browse directly to about.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^tech$ tech.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tech\.php$ tech [L,R]
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ contact [L,R]
```

Comment: this works for `/contact` (the correct page is displayed), but if I go to `/contact.php` I'm not getting redirected to `/contact`

Comment: Missed the improper RegEx in your original solution. Fixed it now. See above