# redirecting files with html extension to files without extension (in url)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have recently changed my website url using htaccess so that my urls will not show file extensions. Now my problem is as I have created a new xml sitemap so that my url will be extensionless!!! the Google webmaster tool is telling me about duplicate content issue!! ie. page and page.html have same title.... so my question is how do i redirect the urls with file extension html to urls with out extension!!! 
this is an example of my website url with html extension

http://www.shenazhpeyk.co.uk/coding-machines.html

I want to redirect and change it to

http://www.shenazhpeyk.co.uk/coding-machines

so that will fix the issue with Google webmaster tools (Please provide me a code for use in htaccess file)

Many Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250356/how-to-redirect-file-php-to-file-but-make-file-point-to-file-php/9250387

Answer (score 2):

Found this code as well.  Not sure if it will accomplish the same thing.  Seems to work for me as does the one above (for PHP).

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I am wondering about the trailing slashes and whether those should be there or omitted?

Comment: I know that I am a late to the party but can you please how you redirected it back to the page without the file extension? I really love your code and am using it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site redirect URLs with `.html` extension and remove it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#redirect to remove the .html extension
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for reply But i am getting following error: The page isn't redirecting properly  this is what i have from before and it works but it won't redirect html pages to without extension ones RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Comment: I found the solution, in case anyone else have same problem! lol!    
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    DirectorySlash Off

    RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
      RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
      RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
      RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]

Note : Not sure if it is correct but it works!

Comment: Amir: Congrats! If this solution works, drop it in as an official answer vs. a comment. That way folks will see it more readily! :)

Comment: What I'm curious about is how to make this sort of thing work, but still use Content Negotiation (+MultiViews) for things like images, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```